# Why stored procedure metadata definitions on an entity in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to configure my application with Spring Boot Data JPA and call a Stored Procedure. However, after searching the web, I find that this approach has to make use of some sort of "entity table".

This can be seen as explained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.11.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures), for example.

But, I am confused as to why one needs to tie stored procedure metadata definitions on an entity? What if I do not have such entity table? Isn't there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some research I am not going to use `Spring Data JPA` for calling stored procedures. Instead I will choose `Spring JDBCTemplate`.

Here is how one can do this:

1) In `pom.xml` add following dependency (note that I am using Spring Boot):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) In your DAO class, inject following:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

3) In your DAO class, you can use something similar to what is given below:

```
    LOGGER.info("Calling stored proc...");
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("test").withProcedureName("test_proc");
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("name", "akshay");
    Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    LOGGER.info("Output from procedure: {}", out.get("fullname"));
    LOGGER.info("Returned from stored proc.");
```

More information can be obtained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s05.html

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The pages you linked, they explain **how** you can call a stored procedure from String Data JPA.

It looks rather odd, I know. They say, you need to define an entity just to piggyback the Stored Procedure call on it.

So why use Spring Data instead of JDBC calls? I can only guess:

- You don't want to deal with opening/closing/caching the JDBC resources.
- Your app has strict rules: every DB access must go through Spring Data

Answer (score 0):

You can call a stored procedure directly by using something like this in your Repository interface

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "test_pkg.in_and_out_test")
String callStoredProc(Long id, String p_method);
```

Comment: Thanks but I believe repository is "table" specific again, isn't it? Example: public interface MyDataRepo extends JpaRepository<MyTable, Long>.
So, if I have say 10 tables and 10 repos, where will be the right place to put declaration you mentioned? Isn't that misleading?